# Sending and receiving arrays over COM

Tags: c++, com, variant, safearray

What is the right way to receive and send arrays over COM?  Here's my attempt so far: a safearray of doubles wrapped in a variant.

```
//takes variant holding safearray of doubles
//returns a similar variant having multipled every element by 2
STDMETHODIMP MyComClass::safearraytimestwo(VARIANT in, VARIANT* out)
{
    CComSafeArray<double> sa_in;
    sa_in.Attach(*in.pparray);
    ULONG size = sa_in.GetCount();

    CComSafeArray<double> *out_sa = new CComSafeArray<double>(size);

    for (long i=0;i<size;i++)
        out_sa->SetAt(i,sa_in[i]*2);

    out = new CComVariant(out_sa);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Problems:
 - currently compilation fails on the loop operation: `error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'ATL::_ATL_AutomationType<DOUBLE>::_typewrapper' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` **edit: solved using `SetAt()` instead of `operator[]`**
 - Should I be declaring `out_sa` on the heap?  Will it get deallocated when `out` gets deallocated (which I can only presume the client will do?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 2:** here is a partial implementation that tries just to return a safearray.

```
STDMETHODIMP CSpatialNet::array3(VARIANT in, VARIANT* out)
{
    CComSafeArray<double> out_sa;
    out_sa.Create(2);
    out_sa.SetAt(0,1.2);
    out_sa.SetAt(1,3.4);
    *out = CComVariant(out_sa);
    out_sa.Detach();
    return S_OK;
}
```

This also fails; lisp reports

```
(vl-load-com)
(setq n (vlax-create-object "sdnacomwrapper.SpatialNet"))
(setq v (vlax-make-variant 1.0))
(vlax-invoke-method n 'array3 v 'newvar)
; error: ActiveX Server returned an error: The parameter is incorrect
```

Replacing `CComSafeArray<double>` with an array of variants produces the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't, the array needs to be allocated on the COM heap so that the client code can properly destroy it.  Use the CComSafeArray::Create() method.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  What about the CComVariant, where should I allocate that?  (I notice CComVariant doesn't have a Create() method)

Comment: Variants are passed by value, *out = CComVariant(array);

Comment: `VARIANT* pvIn, VARIANT** pvOut`

Comment: Ben - why should I do that?  I am now getting exceptions thrown by `sa_in.Attach()` implying that the safearray type does not match double (have also tried passing in safearray of variant and modifying code to suit).  The actual type is `variant(safearray(vbdouble))` as defined in autolisp.

Comment: See my edits above - I can't seem to get either input or output of an array working.  Input throws an exception from `CComSafeArray::Attach`; output produces error messages complaints in visual lisp.

Comment: Turns out the correct way to output was `CComVariant(out_sa).Detach(out);` - the `Detach` method handles setting the `out` pointer appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of Sideshow Bob and Roman R. use

```
ComVariant(out_sa).Detach(out);
```

This has a serious drawback. The  `SAFEARRAY` `out_sa` is passed to the `CComVariant's` constructor and the constructor will make a copy of the `SAFEARRAY`. To avoid a copy better use

```
::VariantInit(out);
out->vt = (VT_ARRAY | VT_R8);
out->parray = out_sa.Detach();
```

As Roman pointed out, you should also start with checking whether `in` really is of type `VT_ARRAY | VT_R8`. Bob's solution has imho a serious fault: `in.parray` is attached to `sa_in` but not detached and thus the destructor will destroy `in.parray`. But by the rules of COM, the function `arraytimestwo(VARIANT in,...`is not allowed to modify the argument `in`. COM is full of traps. Therefore, I think it's better to pass the parameter `in` by reference.

I give a (hopefully!) improved solution and a test function:

```
STDMETHODIMP arraytimestwo(const VARIANT &in, VARIANT* out)
{
  try
  {
    if (in.vt != (VT_ARRAY | VT_R8)) return E_INVALIDARG;
    CComSafeArray<double> sa_out;
    variant_t wrapCopyIn(in);
    sa_out.Attach(wrapCopyIn.parray);
    if (sa_out.GetDimensions() > 1) return E_INVALIDARG;

    for (long i = sa_out.GetLowerBound(0); i <= sa_out.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
       sa_out[i] *= 2;
    //Don't forget
    sa_out.Detach();

    *out = wrapCopyIn.Detach();
  }
  catch (const CAtlException& e)
  {
    // Exception object implicitly converted to HRESULT,
    // and returned as an error code to the caller
    return e;
  }
  return S_OK;
}

void TestArraytimestwo()
{
  CComSafeArray<double> vec(5, 1);
  for (int i = vec.GetLowerBound(); i <= vec.GetUpperBound(); i++) vec[i] = i * 1.1;

  variant_t in, out;
  in.vt = (VT_ARRAY | VT_R8);
  in.parray = vec.Detach();

  if (!SUCCEEDED(arraytimestwo(in, &out)))
  {
   std::cout << "Something went wrong!" << "\n";
   return;
  }

  CComSafeArray<double> sa_out;
  sa_out.Attach(out.parray);
  vec.Attach(in.parray);
  for (int i = vec.GetLowerBound(); i <= vec.GetUpperBound(); i++)
     std::cout << vec[i] << "  " << sa_out[i] << std::endl;

  //Not necessary, but I do it out of habit
  vec.Detach();
  sa_out.Detach();
}
```

Remark: Bob's original function should be like this (skipping try ... catch)

```
STDMETHODIMP arraytimestwoBob(const VARIANT &in, VARIANT* out)
{
  CComSafeArray<double> sa_in;
  sa_in.Attach(in.parray);
  CComSafeArray<double> out_sa(sa_in.GetCount(), sa_in.GetLowerBound());
  for (long i = sa_in.GetLowerBound(); i <= sa_in.GetUpperBound(); i++) out_sa[i] = 2 * sa_in[i];
  sa_in.Detach();//Detach, this function doesn't own in 
  ::VariantInit(out);
  out->vt = (VT_ARRAY | VT_R8);
  out->parray = out_sa.Detach();
  return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to verify this, but taking you on faith I'm marking this the accepted answer (over my previous solution which is working for me, but if the above is correct could easily blow up in future!). Online resources on COM are thin on the ground, thank you for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

Got this working - my code is this (edit: though apparently not without faults - see Dietrich's answer):

```
STDMETHODIMP MyComClass::arraytimestwo(VARIANT in, VARIANT* out)
{
    CComSafeArray<double> sa_in;
    sa_in.Attach(in.parray);
    ULONG size = sa_in.GetCount();
    CComSafeArray<double> out_sa;
    out_sa.Create(size);
    for (long i=0;i<size;i++)
        out_sa.SetAt(i,sa_in.GetAt(i)*2);

    CComVariant(out_sa).Detach(out);
    return S_OK;
}
```

And in Lisp...

```
(vl-load-com)
(setq n (vlax-create-object "mycomdll.MyComClass"))
(setq sa (vlax-make-safearray vlax-vbDouble '(0 . 1)))
(vlax-safearray-fill sa '(1 2))
(vlax-safearray->list sa)
(vlax-invoke-method n 'arraytimestwo sa 'newvar)
(vlax-safearray->list newvar)
```

Things specifically wrong with the original attempts:

- needed to use `Detach` method to assign value to `out`
- needed to attach to `in.parray` not `*in.pparray` (not the same thing)

Comment: `~CComSafeArray` would destroy your [attached] `sa_in` and you are not supposed to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A COM method taking VARIANT parameters is responsible for checking arguments, for catching exceptions and it is not going to actually destroy `[in]` array, so a more accurate implementation on C++ side would be:

```
STDMETHODIMP Foo(VARIANT in, VARIANT* out)
{
    _ATLTRY
    {
        ATLENSURE_THROW(in.vt == (VT_ARRAY | VT_R8), E_INVALIDARG);
        ATLENSURE_THROW(out, E_POINTER);
        VariantInit(out);
        CComSafeArray<DOUBLE>& sa_in =
            reinterpret_cast<CComSafeArray<DOUBLE>&>(in.parray);
        ULONG size = sa_in.GetCount();
        CComSafeArray<DOUBLE> out_sa;
        ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(out_sa.Create(size));
        for(ULONG nIndex = 0; nIndex < size; nIndex++)
            out_sa.SetAt(nIndex, sa_in.GetAt(nIndex) * 2);
        // NOTE: Constructor copies data so it's accurate just inefficient
        ATLVERIFY(SUCCEEDED(CComVariant(out_sa).Detach(out)));
    }
    _ATLCATCH(Exception)
    {
        return Exception;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```