# Exporting Data to COM as a <VARIANT<SAFEARRAY<LONG>>> and then read them at the COM using C++

Tags: c++, com, activex, idl

This is my method at client which tries to send a BSTR SafeArray Variant and a Long SafeArray Variant.
The BSTR data is transmitted fine into the COM, unpacked and read correctly.
However, while trying to read the long array in the COM, the code fails while extracting the array from the VARIANT.
The difference between the two variants is that one is containing BSTR while the other contains long values.
Following is the code at client side.

```
MYAPI int sortArray(int argc, char* argv[], long *arr) {

//pack the argv[] which contains
//filename and modulename
//into a <VAR<SAFEARRAY<BSTR>>> 
CComSafeArray<BSTR> thisBSTRArray;  
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {           
    USES_CONVERSION;        
    thisBSTRArray.Add(SysAllocString(A2W(argv[i])));
}

CComVariant var;
var.vt = VT_ARRAY;
var.parray = thisBSTRArray;

//pack the long array into
//<VAR<SAFEARRAY<LONG>>>

CComSafeArray<LONG> sa_arrayOfLongs(argc);  
//populate the safe array
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {        
    //sa_arrayOfLongs.Add(arr[i]);
    //arrayOfLongs[i] = arr[i];
    sa_arrayOfLongs.SetAt(i, arr[i]);
}   
CComVariant varLongArr; 
CComVariant(sa_arrayOfLongs).Detach(&varLongArr);
/*
varLongArr.vt = VT_ARRAY;   
varLongArr.parray = sa_arrayOfLongs;
*/

long arrC = argc;   
l->SortLongArray(&var, &varLongArr, &arrC, &varLongArr);
//call Activex and retun a pointer to sorted array
//make the input array point to the sorted array
return 0;
```

}

This is my method at the ActiveX where I try to decode

```
STDMETHODIMP CPythonCall::SortLongArray(VARIANT* progSpecs, VARIANT* arr, LONG* arrCnt, VARIANT* outArr ){
//VARIANT progspecs contains a safearray containing BSTR values
//VARIANT arr contains a safearray containing long values

//convert progSpecs to a safearray and then to a string array
VARIANT var = *progSpecs;
CComSafeArray<BSTR> sa_progSpecs;
sa_progSpecs.Attach(var.parray);
ULONG progSpecsSize = sa_progSpecs.GetCount();
char *argv[2];
for (int i = 0; i < (int)progSpecsSize; i++) {
    argv[i]= _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(((BSTR)sa_progSpecs.GetAt(i)));
}
//This works fine. Now I am trying to convert 
//the VARIANT arr into a safe array and then into an array of long values
CComSafeArray<long> sa_longs;
VARIANT var_Longs = *arr;
sa_longs.Attach(var_Longs.parray);
//above line fails
}
```

The Code throws system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception for **var_Longs.parray**

Any guidance on the same would be helpful.

Comment: i followed [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228029/sending-and-receiving-arrays-over-com) to write my code

Comment: Try passing a different, empty variant for the last parameter (which seems to be an `[out]` parameter). I suspect the marshaling code is zeroing out the `[out]` parameter before the call - and since you use the same pointer for two parameters, the `[in]` parameter also gets damaged.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik. Passing a different variant worked.
However, although the function at the COM end executes completely, it throws an exception at the end - System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
Is there some exception that I need to handle here?

Comment: `sa_progSpecs.Attach(var.parray);` is a problem (unless there's also a `Detach` somewhere you don't show). At the end of the function, `sa_progSpecs` will go out of scope and destroy the underlying `SAFEARRAY` pointer. But `progSpecs` still holds this now-dangling pointer; eventually it'll be cleared and will try to destroy it again. Similarly with `sa_longs.Attach(var_Longs.parray);`.

Comment: Be aware that you are leaking memory allocated with `ConvertBSTRToString`. You are also leaking memory allocated by `SysAllocString` - make it `thisBSTRArray.Add(CComBSTR(argv[i]).Detach(), false));` (this minimizes copying, and you can also drop `USES_CONVERSION`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank You for pointing this out. I am working on that.
Meanwhile could you please tell me what is the difference between 
sa_progSpecs = var.parray;
and
sa_progSpecs.Attach(var.parray);
Because, when I am using the first line, the code does not throw exception, while in case of the second there is exception.

Comment: Also @IgorTandetnik can you please direct me to some proper book/tutorial that talks about SafeArrays, CCOMSafeArray, Variants and CCOMVariant - along with memory leak issues.

Comment: The assignment operator makes a copy of its argument, so you end up with two identical `SAFEARRAYs`, one owned by `sa_progSpecs` and another by `var`. Whereas `Attach` takes ownership of the argument, so you end up with two objects both thinking they own the same pointer, and both attempting to destroy it, leading to double destruction. In general, you have to be careful about resource ownership, about who's responsible for destroying what when.

Comment: For a general primer on COM itself (with no library wrappers), I like ["Essential COM"](https://www.amazon.com/Essential-COM-Don-Box/dp/0201634465) the best. ["ATL Internals"](https://www.amazon.com/ATL-Internals-Working-2nd/dp/0321159624) talks about ATL classes like `CComSafeArray` and `CComVariant`. This is the only book on ATL, to my knowledge. Some code samples are buggy though; I was a technical reviewer, I pointed them out, but they weren't fixed. The first edition was higher quality, but if I recall correctly it doesn't talk about `CComSafeArray`, which didn't yet exist at the time.

Comment: Thanks a million @IgorTandetnik. I ensured that I am doing `safeArray.Detach()` and that took care of the exception at the end. Also started reading the books from the library.
If you have some time, I would like to ask you some more queries with lesser constraints on word limit. could you please share a mailer handle or something like that.